# Dart svg ImageElement is not showing up

Tags: html, svg, dart

I try to add a `ImageElement` to a `GElement`. Although the `<image>` element is created under `<g>` properly, it is not showing up. If I copy the `<image>` element created by Dart, and add it to html file beforehand, it shows. I am using the following code snippet:

```
ImageElement aImage = new ImageElement();
aImage.setAttribute('x', '$x');
aImage.setAttribute('y', '$y');
aImage.setAttribute('width', '30');
aImage.setAttribute('height', '30');
aImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png');
group.append(a);
```

Comment: What is a `GroupElement` ? I don't see any `<group>` tag in html5.

Comment: [GElement](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_svg/GElement.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to set the href using getNamespacedAttributes (see [this](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/wc4n0K-i2K8)). Also, make sure the group element is on an SvgSvgElement. This worked for me:

```
svg.SvgSvgElement svgBase = new svg.SvgSvgElement();
svg.ImageElement aImage = new svg.ImageElement();
svg.GElement group = new svg.GElement();


aImage.setAttribute('x', '50');
aImage.setAttribute('y', '50');
aImage.setAttribute('width', '30');
aImage.setAttribute('height', '30');
aImage.getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')['href'] = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png';

group.append(aImage);
svgBase.append(group);
querySelector('#container').append(svgBase);
```

Comment: You are a hero! After two days of trying I used getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')['href']... But what is the difference to .setAttribute("href", link)?